# external monitor stops the booting process - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, hdmi, external-monitor

I have a problem with an external monitor.

Info:

- laptop: HP ZBook with Nvidia Quadro M1000M (4k graphics)
- external monitor: Samsung SyncMaster2032BW
- OS: dual boot with Win 10 + Ubuntu 16.04
- graphic driver: X.Org X server

Issue

Booting to Win 10  works fine. However, when booting to Ubuntu, the booting process is interupted and both screens stay black and I have to do a hard shutdown.

If I disconnect the monitor, boot to Ubuntu and then connect the monitor, go to Settings -> Display it immediately activates the external monitor. After that, everything works fine.

I've tried using HDMI (laptop) to DVI (monitor) but the boot issue persisted. Furthermore, when I disconnected the HDMI the laptop started emitting loud noise.

Can someone help?

regards,
seba

Comment: After installing proprietary drivers the dual boot works with the external monitors, however, on my builtin screen I can't change the resolution :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems this has resolved my issue: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NvidiaMultiMonitors

I can now boot with external monitor connected and change the resolution of the builtin screen by using the nvidia control panel.